# Stochastic integral with respect to a predictable process again predictable?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Suppose $M$ is a local martingale and $\alpha$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-valued predictable process. Then we know that $\langle M\rangle$ is predictable, but is the stochastic integral $\alpha\bullet \langle M\rangle$ again predictable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\alpha\bullet\langle M\rangle$ is predictable, because
$$
\alpha\bullet\langle M\rangle =(\alpha\bullet\langle M\rangle)_- + \Delta(\alpha\bullet\langle M\rangle)
                              =(\alpha\bullet\langle M\rangle)_- +\alpha\cdot\Delta\langle M\rangle, 
$$
and the above last two terms are both predictable.

Comment: And what about the general case (i.e. when $A$ is a predictable process and $B$ a predictable process, is $A\bullet B$ predictable provided the stochastic integral $A\bullet B$ exists?)

Comment: @peer When $A$ is a predictable process, B a predictable process **with finite variation**, then $A\centerdot B$ is predictable, provided the stochastic integral $A\centerdot B$ exists. The proof is same as $\alpha\centerdot M$.