# Stochastic integral of non-negative process integrated with respect to local sub-martingale is local sub-martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

We work on a filtered probability space. Let $H$ be predictable, locally bounded, and non-negative, and let $X$ be a local sub-martingale. The **goal** is to show that the stochastic integral $H\cdot X$ is a local sub-martingale.

**My progess so far**: By the Doob-Meyer decomposition we know that there exists a unique local martingale $M$ and a unique predictable, increasing process $A$ started at $0$ such that $X=M+A$. We know that $H\cdot M$ is a local martingale (since $H$ is predictable and locally bounded, and $M$ is a local martingale). Moreover, $\int H \,dA$ (a pathwise Stieltjes integral) is predictable; this is discussed in [Stochastic integral with respect to a predictable process again predictable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2359162/stochastic-integral-with-respect-to-a-predictable-process-again-predictable).

**My question**: Why is $\int H \,dA$ increasing?

Answer (score 3):

Because $H$ is non-negative and $A$ is increasing.

(I don't have reputation for a comment)